# Turn flushing history in ksh after each command (or stop refreshing it)

Tags: ksh, command-history

I have read that ksh, in contrary to bash, flushes its history after each command.
This may be good for many, but for me, it drives me nuts!

I have several windows opened that are opened for their own tasks, and this history being shared messes up with specific session history of commands.

Is there a way I could disable this flushing, so the history could be appended to the command history at the logout time only?

Or, maybe there is a way to request history not to refresh command line history each time?

Comment: One solution is to set `$HISTFILE` to a different file in each window, so each has its own history. You need to set this before starting ksh, I believe.

Comment: @meuh - I had this idea for a moment but then it will be a mess with leftovers from shells being killed, and so on... Before I embark on this idea I am looking for a simpler one - like an option for history/ksh... At the end, I can give up on ksh and run bash.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have multiple shells running in `screen`. In my .khsrc I would customize several settings, including $PS1 and $HISTFILE (and include the basename of the tty device).

This was relatively easey to reconstruct:

```
tty=$(basename $(tty))
histdir=~/.hist
mkdir -p $histdir
export HISTFILE=$histdir/history.$tty
export PS1=$USER@'$PWD ['$tty'] ${?#0}$ '
exec /usr/bin/ksh
```

Save this as `~/bin/screenshell`, and run `chmod +x ~/bin/screenshell`.
Now you can run `screen` and have separate history files for each window.

```
SHELL=~/bin/screenshell screen
```

Examples:

Window 3

```
    vagrant@/home/vagrant [3] 127$ history
    1       history
    2       error
    3       history
```

Window 4

```
    vagrant@/home/vagrant [4] $ history
    1       history
    vagrant@/home/vagrant [4] $ echo $HISTFILE
    /home/vagrant/.hist/history.4
    vagrant@/home/vagrant [4] $ tty
    /dev/pts/4
```

An alternative would be to run `exec ksh` from `.kshrc`, but you'll need some kind of test to prevent an exec-loop.

Comment: Thank you for your code. I suspect it does not share the history between windows after session is closed, right?

Comment: No, it doesn't. However, the number of history files is limited and it shouldn't be too much work to find and copy commands from other windows. Some answers to similar questions use `$$` as selector, resulting in large numbers of files.